# User Identity of Owincontext and httpcontext

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, owin

We have a MVC web application using Owin, and currently there are a lot of places to get user identity within controller using:

```
ClaimsIdentity signedInIdentity = this.Request.GetOwinContext().Request.User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
```

However, occasionally I found the user identity of httpcontextbase is the same with the identity I got above.

My question is that can I safely replace

```
this.Request.GetOwinContext().Request.User.Identity
```

with

```
this.User.Identity
```

?

Comment: That is fine, and in fact all the tutorial and guides do exactly that.

Comment: Talked to Microsoft staff, they are mapped internally actually, so it is safe to replace.